# class select2 no funciona en dos modales

Tags: jquery, laravel, modal

Hola amigos tengo una consulta, tengo dos modales a los que les agrego la clase "select2" en un input que necesito buscar dinamicamente, la cuestion es que solo me funciona en el modal que codee al ultimo y me deja de funcionar en el que queda codeado primero. Alguna sugerencia?

```
<!--MODAL DE NUEVO EVENTO    -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="nuevoEventoModal" 
 role="dialog" 
 aria-labelledby="nuevoEventoModalLabel">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title" 
      id="nuevoEventoModalLabel">Nuevo Evento</h4>
    </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="formNuevoEvento"  data-toggle="validator" role="form"> 
      <div class="form-group">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input type="hidden" value="{{Auth::user()->idUsuario}}" name="user_id">
        <label>Contacto <br>
          <select name="contacto_id" id="contacto_id" style="width:150%" class="select2">
            <option></option>
              @foreach ($contactos as $contacto)
               <option value={{$contacto->idContacto}}>{{$contacto->nameCont}} {{$contacto->lastNameCont}}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>

           </label> <br>
          <label>Nombre del Evento <input type="text" id="nombreEvento" name="nombreEvento" class="form-control" > </label> <br>
        <label>Fecha del Evento <input type="date" id="fechaEvento" name="fechaEvento" class="form-control" > </label> <br>
        <label>Hora del Evento <input type="time" id="horaEvento" name="horaEvento" class="form-control" > </label> <br>
        <label>Descripcion
        <textarea id="detalleEvento" name="detalleEvento" placeholder="Agrega una descripcion" class="form-control" ></textarea>
        </label><br>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" 
       class="btn btn-default" 
       data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <span class="pull-right">
      <button type="submit" id="agregarNuevoEvento" class="btn btn-primary">
        Agregar
        </button>
       </span>
     </div>
     </form>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Y el segundo modal es igual solo que es el de editar, cuestion que el segundo modal al estar codeado al ultimo si me anda la clase, pero me deja de andar en el primero.

El input en cuesion seria:

```
 <select name="contacto_id" id="contacto_id" style="width:150%" class="select2">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los nombres de los ids deben ser únicos. En ambas etiquetas `select` tienes el mismo id: `id="contacto_id"`

Debes tener nombres de `ids` diferentes en cada caso.

Un saludo.